# Convert String to Date (With different formats)

Tags: java, date, hour

I needed some help converting from String to Date, as you can see there are several topics about it, however what I need to convert is different from what is available on the internet, so I needed someone's help.

The date I usually receive is in the following format: Mon Mar 01 15:19:58 +0000 2021.
I would like to do the conversion as it was: 03/01/2021 15:19:58.
I tried to do it as follows, but it didn't work:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String data = "Mon Mar 01 15:19:58 +0000 2021";
try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(data);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(date);
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: The incoming String needs to match the pattern of the Formatter for the Formatter to parse it.  It sounds like you need two formats - one for incoming data and then another for how you want to render it.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I am certain that your format is available on the internet too. This question seems poorly researched to me, which is why I downvoted. There are literally thousands of pages describing parsing and formatting of dates and times in Java, so please be a lot more precise about how far they helped you and where they fell short.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this format string to do the parsing:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
```

So:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

Once you have the value in `date` you can (re)format it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement and did something like:

```
public class FreeFormatDateConveter {

    private static class DatePatternTuple {
        private final Pattern pattern;
        private final String datePattern;

        DatePatternTuple(final String pattern, final String datePattern) {
            this.pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            this.datePattern = datePattern;
        }

        boolean matches(String candidate) {
            return pattern.matcher(candidate).matches();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
        }
    }

    private static final DatePatternTuple[] DATE_PATTERN_TUPLES = {
            new DatePatternTuple("\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
            new DatePatternTuple("\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
            new DatePatternTuple("\\w{3,4} \\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} \\d{4}", " MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy")
    };


    public static Date freeFormatDateParser(String dateStr) {
        return Stream.of(DATE_PATTERN_TUPLES)
                .filter(t -> t.matches(dateStr))
                .map(DatePatternTuple::dateFormat)
                .filter(t -> matches(t, dateStr))
                .map(t -> parse(t, dateStr))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    private static boolean matches(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat, String dateStr) {
        try {
            dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static Date parse(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat, String dateStr) {
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

if you need any new pattern, just add it to list of that constant array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String data = "Mon Mar 01 15:19:58 +0000 2021";
try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(data);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String expecteddate = format.format(date);
    System.out.println(expecteddate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me, I will leave the solution I used thanks to your help.

```
public String getDataHoraAtual(String data) throws ParseException {
    if(data == null) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
    DateFormat entrada = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
    DateFormat saida = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    Date date = entrada.parse(data);
    return saida.format(date);
}
```